# How to send an email to dynamic email account in Django?

Tags: django, email, django-forms, django-templates

I have a contact form in my template, so that when a user requests information about a house  users can contact different sellers to request information. I don't know how I can send email to different accounts as you know in the system exist multiple sellers.

This is my contact form :

[image]

Where "Nombre" is the name of the user that wants information and "Mail" is the e-mail of the user that wants information.

The seller of the House is who will receive the email.

I can't use that:

EMAIL_HOST_USER =

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =

because not only one person will receive all emails

Comment: `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` are used as the credentials to send the email from. Not to. To send emails to different accounts you just specify them in `send_mail()`.

Comment: But if diferent users can send email from, how can resolve that?

Comment: That is not English.

Comment: Sorry, I try to explain my problem clearly, I understand what happens if  EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD are used, as you commented are used as the credentials to send the email from, but in my case the clients that are logged in my FrontEnd can send an email to different sellers to request information about houses for sale. Do you understand me?

Comment: Yeah. You still need to use the same credentials to send the mail. Just change `to` field to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EmailMultiAlternatives` and customize your `to` list

you can try:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

def view_where_i_send_email(request):
    # some view content

    # vars to render into html email template
    d = Context({'arg_1': arg_1, 'arg_n' : arg_n,})

    # get the template to tge email
    template = "emailtemplate.html"
    htmly = get_template(template)

    # render the template and its content
    html_content = htmly.render(d)


    subject = "Subject"
    from_email = "fromthisemail@domain.com"

    # HERE you add the emails to wich you want to send
    to = [email1]
    to.append(email2)
    to.append(email3)

    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, "", from_email, to)
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```